# Does Qt's QVector3D::operator[] have Undefined Behavior?

Tags: c++, qt

Here is part of Qt's `QVector3D` implementation:

```
class QVector3D
{
public:
    // lot of additional functions
    float &operator[](int i);
private:
    float xp, yp, zp;
};

inline float &QVector3D::operator[](int i)
{
    Q_ASSERT(uint(i) < 3u);
    return *(&xp + i);
}
```

I'm pretty sure that this `operator[]` implementation has UB, because it adds an integer to a pointer, which doesn't actually point to an array.

Am I right that this is UB?

(I just wanted to double check this. Qt is widely used, developed for a long time. It is strange that it has a very trivial UB)

Comment: The code you are referring to is doing pointer-arithmetic, yes. It depends on the alignment of member variables xp, yp,zp. Many implementations do so (the whole Gtk object/inheritance model is built on this), so a compiler who would divert would break quite a lot of code.

Comment: While it is UB, no sane implementation will do the wrong thing here.

Comment: @NathanOliver: yet :)

Comment: @ypnos: as far as I know, this is independent of alignment. It is UB, no matter of alingments.

Comment: Yes my answer was about if it would work or not. It is UB.